# Where is the Azure Storage queue connection string specified in NserviceBus configuration?

Tags: .net, azure, nservicebus

When using AzureStorageQueueTransport i get the error message:

```
System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key (NServiceBus.LocalAddress) was not present in the dictionary.
   at NServiceBus.Settings.SettingsHolder.Get(String key) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Settings\SettingsHolder.cs:line 91
   at NServiceBus.Settings.SettingsHolder.Get[T](String key) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Settings\SettingsHolder.cs:line 23
   at NServiceBus.Azure.Transports.WindowsAzureStorageQueues.AzureQueueNamingConvention.<.cctor>b__0(ReadOnlySettings settings) in c:\BuildAgent\work\4e5353dd260f0a07\src\Transport\NamingConventions\AzureQueueNamingConvention.cs:line 13
   at NServiceBus.Transports.ConfigureTransport.<.ctor>b__1(SettingsHolder s) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Transports\ConfigureTransport.cs:line 21
   at NServiceBus.Features.FeatureActivator.SetupFeatures(FeatureConfigurationContext context) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Features\FeatureActivator.cs:line 109
   at NServiceBus.Configure.Initialize() in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Configure.cs:line 115
   at NServiceBus.Bus.Create(BusConfiguration configuration) in c:\BuildAgent\work\1b05a2fea6e4cd32\src\NServiceBus.Core\Bus.cs:line 19
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.PerformConfiguration(Action`1 moreConfiguration) in c:\BuildAgent\work\a3de8759ee491634\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\GenericHost.cs:line 119
   at NServiceBus.GenericHost.Start() in c:\BuildAgent\work\a3de8759ee491634\src\NServiceBus.Hosting.Windows\GenericHost.cs:line 58
```

This is the endpoint config:

```
public class EndpointConfig : IConfigureThisEndpoint
{
    public void Customize(BusConfiguration configuration)
    {
        configuration.UseTransport<AzureStorageQueueTransport>();
        configuration.UsePersistence<InMemoryPersistence>();
        configuration.EndpointName("employee.messagehandler");
    }
}
```

The app.config:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="AuditConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.AuditConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="Logging" type="NServiceBus.Config.Logging, NServiceBus.Core" />
      <section name="AzureQueueConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.AzureQueueConfig, NServiceBus.Azure.Transports.WindowsAzureStorageQueues" />
  </configSections>
    <Logging Threshold="Debug" />
  <connectionStrings>
      <add name="NServiceBus/Transport" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=..;AccountKey=.." />
  </connectionStrings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <MessageForwardingInCaseOfFaultConfig ErrorQueue="error" />
  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings />
  </UnicastBusConfig>
   <AuditConfig QueueName="audit" />
  <AzureQueueConfig ConnectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=..;AccountKey=.." />
</configuration>
```

I am using NServiceBus.Host.exe not azure hosting.

Comment: I downloaded the source from git and changed line 13 in https://github.com/Particular/NServiceBus.AzureStorageQueues/blob/develop/src/Transport/NamingConventions/AzureQueueNamingConvention.cs to  var queueName = "hardcodedqueuename";

Comment: Try setting the endpoint name before configuring the transport.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it didn't work. Also, I tried a endpoint name without a ".".

Comment: i added this line to the configuration. configuration.OverrideLocalAddress("employee.messagehandler");  But this doesn't seem the correct way to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade your NServiceBus nuget package to use version 5.2.0 or later.

Comment: I assumed that when i downloaded the package from nuget i had the latest version.

Comment: packages.config should indicate what version you're on